# jQuery Mobile MVC Arrow CSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery mobile site that looks different on my Windows Phone emulator and my Windows Phone.

Here is a picture on the Windows Phone emulator:

[image]

On my Windows Phone, I see no white arrows. I only see the gray dots. Here is my mark-up:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<product>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div data-role="button" data-theme="c">
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</div>
<br />
<br />
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{        
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Admin", new { id = item.ID })">
        <h3>@item.Name</h3>
        <p>
            <strong>@item.FoodCategoryName</strong></p>
    </a></li>
}
</ul>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="pager">
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
of @Model.PageCount
@if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort,    currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
}
else
{
    @:<<
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @:< Prev
            }
@if (Model.HasNextPage)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { page = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
}
else
{
    @:Next >
    @Html.Raw(" ")
    @:>>
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually looking in the wrong place:

~/jquerymobile/images/icon-18-white.png

I changed this code:

\Content\jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css

```
.ui-icon,
.ui-icon-searchfield:after {
background:                         #666 /*{global-icon-    color}*/;
background:                         rgba(0,0,0,.4) /*{global-icon-disc}*/;
background-image: url(Content/images/icons-18-white.png) /*{global-icon-set}*/;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-moz-border-radius:                 9px;
-webkit-border-radius:              9px;
border-radius:                      9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems png rendering issue.

if there is another browser for windows phone , you can try to browse same page in another browser.